# jQuery history pushstate and reloading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm using html5s history. Push-state to use browsers back button with a single page application (I am using cordova). So I'm trying to load content dynamically in a div container.

I have a history stack according to this example:-

https://zinoui.com/demo/pushstate/

(in the comments below someone has the same problem:-
https://zinoui.com/blog/single-page-apps-html5-pushstate)

My html-content are separate html-files.

Everything works fine till I'm pressing f5 or browsers reload/refresh button. On page reload I am getting a 404, because the browser try's so call the fake url, which not really exits. 
seems like the browser wants to load the sub-page on itself and not within the index.html. 
In the example above the author doesn't have the dynamic-loaded content in a html file. He receives the html code from somewhere as response, and I am not sure how he did this.

So, I want to reload my page and have the content from the separate page still in the designated area in the index.html

Here is my Code: 
Index.js:

```
   $(function () {

            var load = function (url) {
                $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                })
            };


            $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(history);
                    var $this = $(this),
                        url = $this.attr("id"),
                        title = $this.text();


                    history.pushState({
                        url: url,
                        title: title
                    }, title, url);

                    document.title = title;

                        //here you can see the folder structure
                        load("/pages/" + url + "/" + url + ".html");



                });


            $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {

                var state = e.originalEvent.state;
                if (state !== null) {
                    document.title = state.title;
                    load(state.url);

                }
                else {
                    document.title = 'example title';

                }
            });


        });
```

index.html:

...

```
 <div id="content">

</div>
```

....

the links from another html-file (the main menu is also loaded into content-div from index.html)

```
  <li><a id="sp_termine">&Uuml;bersicht der Termine</a></li>
  <li><a id="sp_termine_aendern">Termin &auml;ndern</a></li>
```

I am really looking forward getting some help!
Thanks <3

Comment: Please post your code you are having issues with so we can see what you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. solution:**

dont fake urls to non existend location. its simply bad style. Use queries (?) or # :

```
index.html#mycoolsubsite
index.html?mycoolsubsite
```

Simply do:

```
window.location="#mycoolsubsite";
```

If the page is reloaded you might want to check if the url points to a subsite:

```
alert(window.location.split("#")[1] || "main"); //will print "main" or if you 'redirected' "mycoolsubsite"
```

**2. solution:**

Learn php or nodejs and implement a router.